Mailto Link Not Working Consistently Across All Browsers, Specifically in Google Chrome
I'm experiencing an issue with a simple mailto link in my web application. The link is intended to open the user's default email client to send an email. The HTML code for the link is as follows:
<a href="mailto:testmail@gmail.com">React us</a>
The problem is that this mailto link does not work consistently across all browsers. Specifically, it does not seem to function properly in Google Chrome, while it works fine in other browsers such as Firefox and Safari.
Details:

Verified that the mail client is set up correctly on the machine.
Tested the link on multiple devices and platforms (Windows, macOS, Android, iOS).
Used different email addresses to see if that makes a difference.
Checked browser settings to ensure that mailto links are allowed.

Is there a more reliable method to implement email links that work consistently across all browsers?

Verified that the mail client is set up correctly on the machine.
Tested the link on multiple devices and platforms (Windows, macOS, Android, iOS).
Used different email addresses to see if that makes a difference.
Checked browser settings to ensure that mailto links are allowed.

